# Make oscillations smoothly increase/decrease when frequency being changed dynamically

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I'm modeling the resonance effect with html5 canvas to animate spring when its reach the resonance.
Also got jquery ui slider (max ranged) that changes frequency (w) of the oscillations dynamically during the animation. The problem is when its changed, for some reason sine wave brokes at some points and the animation is not smooth. This is only happens when changing frequency, with amplitude its much better.
my main function to render each frame is this:

```
function doSways() {
var spring = springs[0],
        a = 0,
        A = params.standParams.A,
        w = params.standParams.w;

animIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnvW, cnvH);
    A = params.standParams.A;       
    w = params.standParams.w;                       

    /*if (w < params.standParams.w) { // with this expression and commented <w = params.standParams.w> it works a bit smoother but still some issues can be noticed, for example sharp increases just after the new change of the frequency (w) on the slider
        w += 0.01;
    }*/

    stand.y = A*Math.sin(a*degToRad*w) + offsetY;       

    stand.draw();
    spring.draw(stand.y, A, w);

    if (a++ >= 360) {           //  avoid overflow
        a = 0;
    }
},
25);
}
```

here's how I change frequency(w) on the slider and assign it to params.standParams.w

```
$( "#standfreq_slider" ).slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 1,
    max: 25,
    step: 1,
    value: 5,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      params.standParams.w = parseInt(ui.value);

    }
  });
 );
```

That if expression in doSways function kinda work but it casues another problem,  I need to know the direction of sliding to determine wether I need to += or -= 0.01..
How to make everything work ideal ?

problem illustration live
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v98jyr67/8/)

Comment: Have you tried the += and -= on your own yet?

Comment: can you mock up a demo in jsfiddle? so that we can see/test whats going on?

Comment: @indubitablee yes sure, https://jsfiddle.net/v98jyr67/8/

Comment: @SkullDev yeah I tried but didnt work

Comment: Do not consider the users's value as your current value, but rather as the current target value. Then, each tick, given your current value, you decide how you make the value evolve towards the target value.

Comment: @GameAlchemist sorry I'm not understanding you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the basic formula for sinusoids:

`V = V0 + A * sin(2 * pi * f * t + phi)`

Where:

- V: current value
- V0: center value
- A: amplitude
- f: frequency (Hz)
- t: time (seconds)
- phi: phase

We want the current value (V) to be the same before and after a frequency change. In order to do that we will need a frequency (f) and phase (phi) before and after the change.

First we can set the first equation equal the the second one:

`V0 + A * sin(2 * pi * f1 * t + phi1) = V0 + A * sin(2 * pi * f2 * t + phi2)`

do some cancelling:

`2 * pi * f1 * t + phi1 = 2 * pi * f2 * t + phi2`

solve for the new phase for the final formula:

`phi2 = 2 * pi * t * (f1 - f2) + phi1`

More mathy version:

[image: final formula]

edited:

check out modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/potterjm/qy1s8395/1/

Comment: how you got rid of `sin` from `V0 + A * sin(2 * pi * f1 * t + phi1) = V0 + A * sin(2 * pi * f2 * t + phi2)` ???

Comment: in the step where I said "do some cancelling": first subtract V0 from both sides (this removes V0). then divide both sides by A. Then inverse sin both sides. What you're left with is `2 * pi * f1 * t + phi1 = 2 * pi * f2 * t + phi2`

Comment: in your case since you're using omega for frequency, it would end up with `phi2 = (w1 - w2) * t + phi1`. I had this problem yesterday, and got it working perfectly.

Comment: you had exactly same problem ?

Comment: same UI problem, yes, just not with springs. I modified your fiddle to work with the equation. I added it to my answer. All the interesting stuff is in your frequency slider change handler. The modulus usage is just to make sure the phase stays between 0 and 2 * pi.

Comment: yeah just checking, really nice solution ! amazing how perfectly it works now

Answer (score 0):

Well the pattern i explain below is one i use quite often.
( It might very well have a name - please S.O. people let me know if so-. )

Here's the idea : whenever you need to want a property evolving in a smooth manner, you must distinguish the **target** value, and the **current** value. If, for some reason, the **target** value changes, it will only affect the **current** value in the way you decided.

To get from the current value to the target value, you have many ways :

• most simple : just get it closer from a given ratio on every tick :

```
current += ratio * (target-current);
```

where ratio is in [0, 1], 0.1 might be ok. You see that, with ratio == 1, current == target on first tick.
 Beware that this solution is frame-rate dependent, and that you might want to threshold the value to get the very same value at some point, expl :

```
var threshold = 0.01 ;
if (Math.abs(target-current)<threshold) current = target;
```

•  You can also reach target at a given speed :

```
var sign = (target - current) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
current  += sign * speedToReachTarget * dt;
```

Now we are not frame-rate dependent (you must handle frame time properly), but you will have 'bouncing' if you don't apply a min/max and a threshold also :

```
if (Math.abs(target-current)<0.01) {
      current = target;
      return;
} 
var sign = (target - current) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
current  += sign * speedToReachTarget * dt;
current = (( sign > 0) ? Math.min : Math.max )( target, current);
```

• and you might use many other type of interpolation/easing.